# Why does the mouse input not work correctly?

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, raycasting

I've spent the past week creating a raycasting algorithm in Python using Pygame, and it ran perfectly fine before I added textures to the walls. But now when running in windowed mode the mouse input does not work properly, and as a solution I made it so that the <kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>e</kbd> keys do the job of turning the camera instead. My code can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159943/raycasting-algorithm-in-pygame), but to run it in windowed mode you'll have to change these lines:

```
WIDTH    = 1360
HEIGHT   = 768

SCREEN   = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

To these lines:

```
WIDTH    = 680 
HEIGHT   = 384

SCREEN   = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
```

So that the entire screen can be seen in windowed mode.

So why is it that the mouse input doesn't work properly, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: check with [`pygame.mouse.get_focused()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_focused) to see if you have focus or not. I suspect that's the issue.

Comment: If this is the issue, what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the window? That's usually how you give it focus.

Comment: No this wouldn't be the issue, the window is definitely selected, and it worked fine before I added textures. I just tested this by adding `print(pygame.mouse.get_focused())` after the line `pygame.mouse.set_pos((WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2))` And `1` was returned. However, this offered a noticeable improvement, and removing the line returns it back to how it was before

Comment: Have you tried fullscreen with textures?

Comment: @TemporalWolf Yes I have, and the mouse input works fine then. But unless I call `print(pygame.mouse.get_focused())` it doesn't work properly in windowed mode, and I have to use the q and e keys to turn the camera.